# INVALID_LOGIN in salesforce

Tags: error, login

I am new to salesforce.
I am trying to trigger the data from soap ui tool to salesforce but receiving the error as below :

```
     <faultcode>INVALID_LOGIN</faultcode>
     <faultstring>INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <sf:LoginFault xsi:type="sf:LoginFault">
           <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_LOGIN</sf:exceptionCode>
           <sf:exceptionMessage>Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.</sf:exceptionMessage>
        </sf:LoginFault>
```

The username is working fine when i am logging in directly via salesforce page.
I am using valid username , password and security token.

Appreciate your expert help on the same.

Comment: By default an org locks you out for 15 minutes if you make several invalid login attempts try again after 15 minutes. Presume you are appending the security token to the end of the password? Also note that there is a different login URL for sandboxes (https://test.salesforce.com/ vs https://login.salesforce.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Please use your user security token in login api call. It should be appended after user password.
Here is a sample SOAP UI request for login that works perfectly:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>         
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login>
         <urn:username>salesforceusername@domainname.com</urn:username>
         <urn:password>[userpassword][UserSecurityToken]</urn:password>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To get your security token :

1. Click on your name in Salesforce login.
2. Choose My Settings
3. Personal -> Reset my Security Token.

You will receive a email containing your token.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your build.properties folder. If you are trying to retrieve data from a sandbox then use **sf.serverurl = https://test.salesforce.com** .
          Similarly, if you want to retrieve data from production then use **sf.serverurl = https://login.salesforce.com**. Please let me know if you want any further details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently changed the password, you need to update that password in the build.ci.properties file and then you can successfully run the commands.